# What prestige classes include the Class Feature of "+1 level of existing class features"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, prestige-class

I'm looking for prestige classes from D&D 3e *or* 3.5e that have a class feature of providing "+1 level of existing class features". I currently know of Uncanny Trickster (CS) and Legacy Champion (WoL). Are there any more?

Comment: What specifically are you after that is not provided by just taking an extra level in the class you would be applying that to?

Comment: @Caleth Probably in an attempt to artificially extend a short prestige class's class features or something similar; see [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62151/8610).

Answer (score 3):

**I believe there not to be.**

I have searched through all of my books (I own all 3.0/3.5 books, except for the dungeon-tile publications, all of my magazines (Dragon and Dungeon) dating from TSR to Paizo, and several Mongoose and Sword and Sorcery publishing books.

Those are literally the only two examples I could find as well. I even used three differen't search engines, Bing, Google, and Yahoo, and only found those two examples.

If there are other 3rd party material that has a similar prestige class special ability, I will stand corrected. But I strongly do believe, those are the only two prestige classes available outside of homebrew.

Comment: Casting an even wider net, the *Pathfinder* prestige class [evangelist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/evangelist) comes close at level 2.

Answer (score -6):

I have found a racial Paragon Class at dandwiki.com called the Aasimar Paragon class and it has your "+1 to existing class features", class feature. That's not really a prestige class though... The Factotum at level 20 can assume a class feature from up to three different base classes with his inspiration points, still not a prestige class... As you have already stated the Uncanny trickster and Legacy Champion are two prestige classes that have this class feature to them.

But don't worry I have hope!

Under the Dungeon masters guide II page 203 their is an entire section on DESIGNING
PRESTIGE CLASSES!!

Upon which you could construct using that guideline any and all further modifications to your game or bring said prestige class to your GM and ask his approval to add it to his world.

Comment: dandwiki is full of (often poor) homebrew that often appears to be official; is the class you are referring to actually a thing, or something someone made up (I strongly suspect the latter)? And yes, homebrew (either existing or making your own) is always an option, but it's not an answer to this question.

Comment: The point I made was that their is no other classes that grant that ability I have all the books and dragon mags.

Comment: I have almost all of the books, quite a lot of the *Dragon* magazines, and furthermore have access to quite a few tools, indices, and such for 3.5 material, not to mention a massive amount of experience with that material, and I’d be hesitant to make the absolute claim that there aren’t any other such classes buried in there somewhere. It’s difficult to prove a negative, but you haven’t even attempted to do so, e.g. by listing books that you’re sure *don’t* have such a class, or by linking to others who corroborate your claim, or *something*.

Comment: @KRyan I have gone through all of them page by page looking for this feature in class, base and presige, they simply did not print another class with that feature. So I listed what I could about it by out sourcing to homebrew sites to add the further options to an answer that is simply no their are no other classes.